# Use the implicit operator while preserving some previous data

Tags: c#

To make a save system that can do versionning, I want to associate a version number to a data. So I created a generic class to handle that with implicit operators for convenience:

```
public class VersionedData<T>
{
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
    
    public VersionedData()
        : this(default(T), 0)
    {
    }

    public VersionedData(T data, int version = 0)
        :base(data, version)
    {
        Version = version;
        Data = data;
    }

    public static implicit operator T?(VersionedData<T> vd) => vd.Data;
    public static implicit operator VersionedData<T>(T data) => new VersionedData<T>(data, 0);
}
```

An exemple of usage would be to have a class that old save data:

```
public class Save
{
    public VersionedData<string> Name { get; set; } = "";
    public VersionedData<int> Age { get; set; } = new (data: 21, version: 1);
}
```

But to edit the age without losing the existing version associated to the data, I need to write:

```
var save = new Save();
save.Age.Data = 18;
```

Is there a way to write `save.Age = 18;` without loosing the Version value of the previous VersionedData?

I guess this isn't possible in C#, but perhaps you have an idea of how to achieve a similar aproach?

Comment: *"without loosing the Version value of the previous VersionedData?"* - huh? i didnt see anything that store the previous version.. and everything is defaulted to version 0 for some reason.

Comment: Indeed when you write ` = 18;` there is no way to know what is before the = and give it to the implicit operator.
What you can do is creating a Set method : `save.Age.Set(18);` but I guess you don't want this.

Comment: How about a custom setter for `Age`/`Name`? But then you won't be able to change the version with `= new VersionData(...)`. You *have* to set the `Version` property.

Comment: If you really want to write `save.Age = 18;` you would need to modify the Save class to encapsulate your data and change the setters : `public VersionedData<int> Age { get => age; set => age = new VersionedData<int>(value, age.Version); }`

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to do this if instead of using auto-props you implement the [properties (= accessors)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) yourself.

```cs
public class Save
{
    private VersionedData<string> _name = "";

    private VersionedData<int> _age = new(data: 21, version: 1);

    public string Name
    {
        set { _name.Data = value; } // or: set => _name.Data = value;
        get { return _name.Data; }  // or: get => _name.Data;
    }

    public int Age
    {
        set { _age.Data = value; } // or: set => _age.Data = value;
        get { return _age.Data; }  // or: get => _age.Data;
    }
}
```

In `Program.cs` you can then call it like this:

```cs
var save = new Save();
Console.WriteLine(save.Age);
save.Age = 18;
Console.WriteLine(save.Age);
```

This will print:

```
21
18
```

Not sure though why you would wanna change the data without updating the version. To my mind that does defeat the purpose of versioning.

But you could also increase the version number in the setter if you want/ need to.

Comment: yes, my question was not very clear concerning the purpose of the version. I will use the version in case the software need make the data evolve. and this version will be read from the save and could be converted into the new software version at deserialization.

So I don't need to change the version except at default initialisation of the data value.

Thanks for the properties idea, I was hopping to avoid this kind of code, I like when only adding a new field is enought to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would create two factory methods inside the class `VersionedData<T>`: One static method to create the first data version and one instance method to create the next version from the existing one:

```cs
public static VersionedData<T> CreateFirst(T data) => new(data, 1);

public VersionedData<T> CreateNext(T data) => new(data, Version + 1);
```

Usage:

```cs
var data = VersionedData<int>.CreateFirst(18); // Version = 1
var next = data.CreateNext(19);                // Version = 2
```

You could even make the constructor(s) private to force usage of these Create... methods.

Comment: Thanks, I think the utility of the version was not well explained. The purpose of version is to store the version of the default data stored, and if at some point in the software development this data need to evolve or change, thanks to the version saved, I will be able to convert it to the new version of the data.

So this approch is not why I need, to auto-increment the version each time I update the data.